# Get data from client side html into google sheets using cheerio - columns not populating

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm looking pull data from 248 different URLs with different page structures. The majority of the pages list email addresses in the html right behind a `mailto:` string so I've used said string as an identifier my google apps script to grab the email and build around. The email data is then placed in col A of my `[IMPORT]` tab.

I'd also like to pull any non-markup text from 7 hierarchical elements above and the 3 below the element holding the email address. That data should be placed in cols B - K of the `[IMPORT]` tab.

**What works**
The script *correctly* pulls in all the email addresses and the non-markup text from the first element above the email addresses. It places this data in col A (const `email`) and col B (const `defaultElementAbove`) of the `[IMPORT]` tab.

**What doesn't**
Anything beyond the first two columns for `Email` and `Default Element Above` don't populate, including the column headers.

Here's my script:

```
function extractEmailAddresses() {
  var sheetName = "[IMPORT]";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var urlsSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("urls");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Clear previous data in the sheet
  sheet.clearContents();

  // Add headers
  sheet.appendRow(["Email", "Default Element Above", "Two Elements Above", "Three Elements Above", "Four Elements Above", "Five Elements Above", "Six Elements Above", "Seven Elements Above", "One Element Below", "Two Elements Below", "Three Elements Below"]);

  // Loop through each URL
  for (var i = 1; i <= urlsSheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var url = urlsSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    console.log("URL:", url); // Log the URL for debugging

    try {
      var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

      // Use Cheerio to parse the HTML
      var $ = Cheerio.load(html);

      // Extract email address
      var email = $("a[href^='mailto:']").attr("href");
      email = email ? email.substring(7) : "";

      // Extract elements above and below the email
      var defaultElementAbove = "";
      var twoElementsAbove = "";
      var threeElementsAbove = "";
      var fourElementsAbove = "";
      var fiveElementsAbove = "";
      var sixElementsAbove = "";
      var sevenElementsAbove = "";
      var oneElementBelow = "";
      var twoElementsBelow = "";
      var threeElementsBelow = "";

      if (email) {
        var emailElement = $("a[href^='mailto:']");

        // Elements above email
        defaultElementAbove = emailElement.prev().text().trim();
        twoElementsAbove = emailElement.prev().prev().text().trim();
        threeElementsAbove = emailElement.prev().prev().prev().text().trim();
        fourElementsAbove = emailElement.prev().prev().prev().prev().text().trim();
        fiveElementsAbove = emailElement.prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text().trim();
        sixElementsAbove = emailElement.prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text().trim();
        sevenElementsAbove = emailElement.prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text().trim();

        // Elements below email
        oneElementBelow = emailElement.next().text().trim();
        twoElementsBelow = emailElement.next().next().text().trim();
        threeElementsBelow = emailElement.next().next().next().text().trim();
      }

      // Append data to the sheet
      var row = [
        email,
        defaultElementAbove,
        twoElementsAbove,
        threeElementsAbove,
        fourElementsAbove,
        fiveElementsAbove,
        sixElementsAbove,
        sevenElementsAbove,
        oneElementBelow,
        twoElementsBelow,
        threeElementsBelow
      ];

      sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log("Error processing URL:", url);
      Logger.log("Error:", error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Why can't I get columns C - K to populate?

There's not always data in those elements on every page but for some reason the headers aren't even being properly written into the spreadsheet.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `What doesn't Anything beyond the first two columns for Email and Default Element Above don't populate, including the column headers.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, can you provide a sample URL for testing your script?

Comment: No worries @Tanaike . The script is supposed to run and grab `email` addresses off the page and place those in column A of my `[IMPORT]` tab on my spreadsheet. It then proceeds to grab the non-markup text from the 7 elements above where the email was found and the 3 below, and put those in columns B - K of the same spreadsheet. Right now only cols A & B are populating.

Sample URLs here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cNzxjMQrwGrXVIZMazTX7jKG7krkDay73JZWeAu3-aQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Tanaike I also reworded the question so it makes more sense. Thanks for flagging.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your script using your provided URLs, it seems that all values of `row` are empty except for only one URL. And also, even when only one URL is used, only the values of `email` and `twoElementsAbove` have the values. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.